# Has anyone got an example of Delphi's Android access to the USB class?

Tags: android, delphi, usb

I am creating a Delphi XE5 Android app that will ultimately talk to a small micro via a USB connection (possibly using HID but this is open yet). I have a Delphi-generated working app now using XE5, running on a Nexus tablet and I need to start on the USB side of things. There is a lot of information out there about Android and USB and I see that the java class is `android.hardware.usb`. Delphi already imports the camera class from `android.hardware` but I know little about how to start my own class to import the USB stuff. There is some [information here](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=96187) that hints of some work by one developer but no example. I'm happy with block transfers but I need to get a start with translating the class. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you're still looking for this, I have some working example code over here Delphi <a href="http://www.bverhue.nl/g2dev/?p=65" >Android USB Interface with the G2</a> (http://www.bverhue.nl/g2dev/?p=65) This example is about interfacing with a synthesizer over USB in host mode, but as an example it might be usefull.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an example of Delphi's Android access to the USB class, but I would like to point you a commercial application, [Android 2 Delphi Import Tool](http://journeyman.ath.cx/Android2DelphiImport.aspx) which can generate Delphi import units to any Android classes.